# Android - share FBO texture created in background context to main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es, textures, fbo

I need to use FBO in background thread because it causes strong UI freeze(about 0.5 sec) on some Android devices (It is needed to recreate about 25 FBO objects every 3-5 secs), I have successfully created background context using EGL14, also rendering to FBO works as expected, but.... I totally can't understand how to share FBO texture with the main thread!

I tried to use texture id's, which are created in the background thread, but this id's already exist in the main thread and relates to another texture or they have no texture at all. 
I searched a lot, but I can't find any example code how to share texture correctly to main thread on Android. Please provide any solution or link where explained how to use texture (created on the background thread) in the main thread, created with GLSurfaceView.

Some parts of code

Initializing of background context:

```
private boolean createEglContext() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        if (mEglDisplay == null) {
            mEglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);
            if (mEglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
                return false;
            }

            int[] version = new int[2];
            if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(mEglDisplay, version, 0, version, 1)) {
                mEglDisplay = null;
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (mEglConfig == null) {
            int[] eglConfigAttribList = new int[]{
                    EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,    // very important!
                    EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,          // we will create a pixelbuffer surface
                    EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
                    EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
                    EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
                    EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,     // if you need the alpha channel
                    EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,    // if you need the depth buffer
                    EGL_NONE
            };
            int[] numEglConfigs = new int[1];
            android.opengl.EGLConfig[] eglConfigs = new android.opengl.EGLConfig[1];
            if (!EGL14.eglChooseConfig(mEglDisplay, eglConfigAttribList, 0,
                    eglConfigs, 0, eglConfigs.length, numEglConfigs, 0)) {
                return false;
            }
            mEglConfig = eglConfigs[0];
        }


        int[] ctxAttrib = {
                EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };

        if (mEglContext == null) {
            mEglContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(mEglDisplay, mEglConfig,
                    EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ctxAttrib, 0);
            if (mEglContext == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        int[] surfAttr = {
                EGL14.EGL_WIDTH, viewPortWidth,
                EGL14.EGL_HEIGHT, viewPortHeight,
                EGL14.EGL_NONE
        };

        mEglSurface = EGL14.eglCreatePbufferSurface(mEglDisplay, mEglConfig, surfAttr, 0);

        if (mEglSurface == null) {
            return false;
        }

        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEglDisplay, mEglSurface, mEglSurface, mEglContext);

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Initializing FBO on the background thread:

```
...
    GLES20.glGenFramebuffers(1, frameObject, 0);
        textureObject = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureObject, 0);
        GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, textureObject[0]);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
        GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureObject[0], 0);

        int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
        if (status != GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        }

....
```

After initializing of the FBO/rendering to the FBO completed, I am trying to pass generated texture id to the main thread - but no success. The displayed texture is always incorrect or there is no texture at all.

Initializing of the background thread, rendering to FBO - all working good and there is not any glError's. I am using OpenGL ES 2.0.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can only share things within a context share group. When you create the second context you need to set it to use the first context as it's parent. Create the main rendering context first, and when creating the loading thread context pass the main context as the `share_context` parameter of `eglCreateContext()`. See:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglCreateContext.xhtml

Currently you are passing `EGL_NO_CONTEXT`, which explains why there is no sharing between them happening.

However note that not all resources can be shared. Data resources - e.g. textures, buffers, and shaders, etc are fine and can be shared. Objects which purely manage state such as FBOs and VAOs are not shareable. If the performance issue you are hitting is FBO creation - rather than the texture data management - then using a second context isn't going to help ...